# How to print from a selection of checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I need to create these output according to the checked:

**produttore + struttura = 60 or produttore = 45 or struttura = 56**
starting from here if it is easier

```
$(".rambo").change(function () {
var str = "";
      $("input:checked").each(function () {
            var valore = $(this).val();
            switch(valore)
                    {
                        case "produttore": str += "produttore";                                            
                        break;
                        case "struttura": str += "struttura";
                        break;
                        default:;
                    }
          });
      $("div").html(" <b>Multiple:</b> " + str);

    })
    .change();
```

and this

```
<input type="checkbox" class="rambo" value='produttore' /> 45 euro
<input type="checkbox" class="rambo" value='struttura' /> 56 euro
```

thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".rambo").change(function () {
var str = "";
var num = 0;
      $("input:checked").each(function () {
            var valore = $(this).val();
            if(str != "")
            {
               str += " + ";
               num = 60;
            }
            switch(valore)
                    {
                        case "produttore": 
                           str += "produttore";
                           if(num == 0) num = 45;                                            
                        break;
                        case "struttura": 
                           str += "struttura";
                           if(num == 0) num = 56;
                        break;
                        default:;
                    }
          });
      str += " = " + num;
      $("div").html(" <b>Multiple:</b> " + str);

    })
    .change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example will get you started. For inputs I added an extra data attribute

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="rambo" value='produttore' data-amt="45 euro" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFzPK/

```
var textSeparator = ' + ';


$(".rambo").change(function() {
    var str = [];
    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        var valore = $(this).val();
        str.push($(this).val() + ' = ' + $(this).data('amt'));
    });
    $("div").html(" <b>Multiple:</b> " + str.join(textSeparator));

}).change();
```